# Can't find path of the img inside div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get path of image and assing it to the src of `manset_foto` I have this code I could not find what is wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

     var path = $('div#onIzlemeler img:first-child').attr('src');

    $('#manset_foto').css('display', 'none').fadeIn('slow').attr('src', path);
    $('div#onIzlemeler img').mouseenter(function () {
      $('#manset_foto').css('display', 'none').fadeIn('slow').attr('src', $(this).att('src'));
                });
            });
</script>

<div id="onIzlemeler">
    <img src="slider/1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="slider/2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="slider/3.jpg" alt="abla" />
    <img src="slider/4.jpg" alt="!" />
    <img src="slider/5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

 <div id="manset">
        <img id="manset_foto"/>
        <p id="manset_bilgi"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're not using the `path` value that you extracted...

Comment: @Lix , you are right!

Comment: I am sorry. I just did a mistake while I was writing it here. I am using the same path in my code and edited it now.

Comment: Suggestion: if you already selecting element with it's id then no need to give the element name before the id. You select element like 'div#id', recommended '#id'.

Comment: I found the wrong part. At the last part of code `$(this).att('src'))`
I have wrote `att` instead of `attr`. It is embarrassing o_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use variable `path`

```
 var path = $('div#onIzlemeler img:first-child').attr('src');
 $('#manset_foto').css('display', 'none').fadeIn('slow').attr('src', path);
```

Currently You are using `yol`

### EDIT

use `.attr()` instead of `.att()`

Your other mistake is in line `.attr('src', $(this).att('src'))`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rz29V/)

Comment: I just wrote it here wrong. In my code I am using path value but it still not working.

Comment: @Blast, I have pointed out your second mistake and provided a demo

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing "r" of `.attr()` method here:

```
$('#manset_foto').css('display', 'none').fadeIn('slow')
                 .attr('src', $(this).att('src'));
                //----------------------^----here "r" is missing in .attr()
```